# How to get text of elements INCLUDING any values in input fields using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing a search box to hide elements which do not contain the search string. The code is quite simple:

```
function searchFilter(root, selector, regex) {
    root.find(selector).filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle(regex.test($(this).text()));
    });
}
```

This works beautifully for most things. But, when the searched items are divs or table rows containing `input` fields, the search does not take any notice of data input into the field, just the rest of the text of the div.

Is there an easy way to get the text of an html element, including contained elements, which also includes the values of `input` fields?

I have implemented what I consider to be a hack, but grateful for better ideas or improvements:

```
function getValues(selector) {
    var v = [];
    $(selector).find('input').each(function () {
        v.push($(this).val()); 
    });
    return v.join(' ');
}

function searchFilter(root, selector, regex) {
    root.find(selector).filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle(regex.test($(this).text() + ' ' + getValues(this)));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursively walk DOM nodes and gather either value (in the node has `value` property) or text:

```js
const toggle = str => searchFilter($('table'), 'tr', new RegExp(str));

function searchFilter(root, selector, regex) {
    root.find(selector).filter(function () {
        const text = getText(this);
        console.log('text of', selector, ':', text);
        $(this).toggle(regex.test(text));
    });
}

function getText(elem){
debugger;
  let text = '';
  if(elem.childNodes.length){
    text += [...elem.childNodes].map(getText).join('');
  }else{
    text += 'value' in elem ? elem.value : elem.textContent;
  }
  return text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>Some label:</td><td><input value="test"></td></tr>
</table>
<button onclick="toggle('Some label:test')">Find Some label:test</button>
<button onclick="toggle('Some label:hide')">Find Some label:hide</button>
```

Comment: Thankyou - but selector is probably a div or table row, containing lots of elements, including maybe some inputs. Have improved the question to make that clear.

Comment: @NikkiLocke you've confused this answer's `root` parameter - `root` is the selector for the parent, eg `div#myid` and `selector` is which elements, eg `td,input,select`  - the regex parameter then checks the value/text to toggle the selector.   Note that `.filter` is mis-used here and should be .each, but it's not a major issue.

Comment: Root is a table. Selector is table rows (so it is whole rows that disappear). A row will never have a value.

Comment: @NikkiLocke understood finally

Comment: @NikkiLocke fixed, enjoy